# Can't access IIS over a LAN in both ways

Tags: lan, iis, iis-7.5

I've been having a problem with IIS that I can't solve:

I have 2 PCs connected in the same LAN (let's call them A & B). Both of them run on Windows 7, with IIS 7.5. Both PCs have (inside wwwroot) a folder with a simple `.html` file. My problem is that although I can access the the A page from B, I **can't** access the B page from A.

Furthermore, when I put the LAN ip from A in A's Chrome explorer (192.168.2.4) it shows IIS startpage, but when I do the same in B (with 192.168.2.3), it says

> Could not establish connection

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be firewall (is port 80 open). Or the IIS set up is wrong - I suggest you load IIS on PC B, and find to the .html file and right click-> browse to check the URL. Then, rename the localhost to the IP in question.

However, the issue sounds like a binding problem. So, just bind the IP to the site (unless you're using dynamic IP). Or, even better, do it by computer name. EG `http://computerName/`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to be useful, but i couldn't fix it... I ended up reinstalling my PC cause it was almost breaking down... I'm sure IIS was already corrupt and didn't do what it was suppossed to do. Thanks!!